# Best practice to get json from url in api 23

Tags: android, apache-httpclient-4.x, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm using `compileSdk 23` with support library version 23.

I've used httplegacy library (I've copied it into *app/libs* folder from *androidSdk/android-23/optional/org.apache.http.legacy.jar*) and in gradle I've put:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

In order to load that library.

Into my Connection class I've got a method to load an instance of `DefaultHttpClient` in this way:

```
private static HttpClient getClient(){
    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    int timeoutConnection = 3000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
    int timeoutSocket = 3000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

    return httpClient;
}
```

But Android Studio says me that all `apache.http` classes are deprecated.

What could I use in order to follow best practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a reason why this it was deprecated.
according to [this official page](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client):

> This preview removes support for the Apache HTTP client. If your app
>   is using this client and targets Android 2.3 (API level 9) or higher,
>   use the HttpURLConnection class instead. This API is more efficient
>   because it reduces network use through transparent compression and
>   response caching, and minimizes power consumption

Therefore, you better use [HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html):

```
   URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
   HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   try {
     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
     readStream(in);
    finally {
     urlConnection.disconnect();
   }
 }
```

Another option is to use a network library. I personally uses [Fuel](https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel) on my Kotlin code (but it has Java support) and [Http-request](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request) on my Java code. Both of the libraries use `HttpURLConnection` internally.

Here is an example for connecting using `Http-Request` library:

```
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.get("http://google.com");
String body = request.body();
int code = request.code();
```

And here is an example for connecting using `Fuel` library:

```
Fuel.get("http://httpbin.org/get", params).responseString(new Handler<String>() {
    @Override
    public void failure(Request request, Response response, FuelError error) {
        //do something when it is failure
    }

    @Override
    public void success(Request request, Response response, String data) {
        //do something when it is successful
    }
});
```

Note: `Fuel` is async library, `Http-request` is blocking.

Comment: Wonderful! thank you! i will use Http-Request because every request in my application are wrapped in an asyncTask.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my complete example:

```
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject json = null;
    static String output = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List params) {
        URL _url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;

        try {
            _url = new URL(url);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) _url.openConnection();
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error due to a malformed URL " + e.toString());
            return null;
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "IO error " + e.toString());
            return null;
        }

        try {
            is = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder(is.available());
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line).append('\n');
            }
            output = total.toString();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "IO error " + e.toString());
            return null;
        }
        finally{
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }

        try {
            json = new JSONObject(output);
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return json;
    }
}
```

Given a payload that returns `{"content": "hello world"}`, use like this:

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject payload = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(
        "http://yourdomain.com/path/to/your/api",
        null);
System.out.println(payload.get("content");
```

It should print out `"hello world"` in your console.

Comment: Shouldn't it print out "hello world"?

Comment: PLEASE... PLEASE... PLEASE...   I realy need this... can you help-me? Once I put youe example in my code, I receive the error in the console: "at jp.co.e_grid.rakuseki.PostConfirmationActivity$1JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(PostConfirmationActivity.java:150)"

Comment: AND the line with error is "is = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());"

Comment: Why did you make `is`, `json` and `output` static? That seems very thread-unsafe to me.